# python question about iterative functions/ general functions

Tags: python, function

I have the following code, which i know to be wrong and also know what exactly is wrong, lack of 'return' before both iterative calls:

```
alpha = 546
beta = 66

def Euclid(a, b):
    while not (a == 0 or b == 0):
        if a >= b:
            Euclid(a % b, b)
        else:
            Euclid(a, b % a)

    return max(a, b)

print(Euclid(alpha, beta))
```

My question is why does the code above not still work? I viewed it in code visualiser, and it shows that the last value it returns is indeed max(a,b), so GCD, but then after the function keeps executing the code forever, going from arguments of (6,12) to (6,0), and then starting all over again with (6,12), after returning (6,0). Would just like to know what exactly is happening, since i thought function always quits after the last return.

Comment: How _could_ it work? Remember, just calling a child function doesn't change your own arguments, or set your own return value, so `a` and `b` never change; thus, `a == 0 or b == 0`, if it wasn't true in the arguments you're first passed, will never have a chance to _become_ true. If you run the `Euclid` functions but throw away the results, it's as if they never happened at all.

Comment: Be sure that whatever "code visualiser" you're using shows you stack frames. The function isn't _starting over_; instead, it's _calling itself_. When you recurse, you start a new instance of the function, but the old one is still there on the stack, unfinished until execution gets back to it and it's able to `return`.

Comment: Please tell us how to exit a ``while True`` without exiting a ``while True``.

Comment: Also that while loop doesn't seem to be making sense. You seem to want to do things recursively but seem to be attempting to add iteration anyway inside it. Maybe you just need an if condition instead. In this particular case you should either use a while loop or use recursion, both together doesn't make sense.

Comment: You return an integer (the maximum out of a or b), and don't assign it to anything.  So,  the ***recursive*** calls to `Euclid` do ***nothing***.  *(Don't start it with a capital, that usually implies a Class)*.  Perhaps you wanted to use the returned result to change the value in `a` or `b`?  In which case, you're missing `a =` and/or `b =`...

Comment: Say, we assume there's no `if`, `else`, essentially what you have boils down to `while not <cond>`. How's it going to branch our. Put differently, when will the condition change. Note: to compound, your `if` and `else` recursively call the `Euclid()` function with the same arg (parameter passed). Inbtw, Python convention uses lowercase for functions and capitalised for Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your Euclid function and try to understand what happens line by line (and also pay close attention to the values of the variables):

```
def Euclid(a, b):
    while not (a == 0 or b == 0):
        if a >= b:
            Euclid(a % b, b)
        else:
            Euclid(a, b % a)

    return max(a, b)
```

- You call it with a = 546 and b = 66. (a=546 and b=66)
- You enter the while loop because a!=0 and b!=0 (a=546 and b=66)
- Since a>=b you call the Euclid function with a%b and b (a=546 and b=66)
- You ignore the return value (a=546 and b=66) (actually this call never returns either, but let's assume for now it does)
- You go back to the start of your while loop and start again (a=546 and b=66)

The problem is that you never modify the values of a and b, so your while condition will always be true, and your first call of the function never reaches the return.

Ps.: B Remmelzwaal is right about how to fix your code, I only explained what is happening, which makes you get stuck in an infinite loop. Based on his answer the correct code would be:

```
def Euclid(a, b):
    while not (a == 0 or b == 0):
        if a >= b:
            return Euclid(a % b, b)
        else:
            return Euclid(a, b % a)

    return max(a, b)
```

Ps2.: To clarify some misunderstanding, the while loop is un necessary in the code, since you would enter only once and return from it. The commands inside the while are never repeated.

The code which reflects better what is happening would be:

```
def Euclid(a, b):
    if a!=0 and b!=0:
        if a >= b:
            return Euclid(a % b, b)
        else:
            return Euclid(a, b % a)

    return max(a, b)
```

So in this case when you call the function with a = 546 and b = 66, the following is going to happen:

- Euclid(546,66)
- - Euclid(18,66)
- - - Euclid(18,12)
- - - - Euclid(6,12)
- - - - - Euclid(6,0) --> This is not calling any more Euclids and returns 6
- - - - - return 6
- - - - return 6
- - - return 6
- - return 6
- return 6

So the Euclid(6,0) gives you 6, the Euclid(6,12) returns the return value of Euclid(6,0), which was 6. And so on while you reach back to the Euclid(546,66).

You can imagine it as a matryoshka doll, every outer doll tells you the number which the inner doll told it. In this analogy the smallest inner doll is the Euclid(6,0) and every other doll just repeats it as it proceeds through the layers.

Comment: I do not see the problem. Yes, the 2nd call of the Euclid function will be with parameters 18 and 66. In my explanation I am only talking about the 1st call.

When you call a function a 2nd time it does not modify the input of the first call (at least in this case).

Comment: Completely misread that, I thought at the third bullet point you meant those `a` and `b` were the parameters to the new function. My mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I see, so return before each call would update the values.

Comment: No, the return does not update the values. The return finishes the execution of that specific instance of the function (basically makes you stop at the 4th bullet point). Also the "while" call is pointless in the code, since you are returning from it (you never repeat the actions in the while loop). I'll add some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Didn't realize that all returns return a single digit, but your answer definitely clears it up. Thanks so much for the effort. See the problem with the while loop too, will take note for sure.